# Error Cannot read property en NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongoose, pug

Estoy programando una aplicación web y tengo este error hace semanas, este es el error:

> Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined

Es del mismo modo la vista pug, solo que la puse acá como código porque no me dejaba publicar, surge al querer enviar los datos en el Post:

> Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined
> TypeError: C:\Users\Notebook\Documents\curso node\node-y-mongo\red_bicicletas\views\usuarios\create.pug:18
> 16|     .form-group
> 17|         label(for='nombre') Nombre:
> 18|         input#nombre.form-control(type='text' name='nombre' value=usuario.nombre class=errors.nombre ? 'is-invalid' : '')
> 19|         if errors.nombre
> 20|             small#nombreHelp.text-danger
> 21|                = errors.nombre.message

Este es el código de controller's del usuario, el error supuestamente esta en la línea de código de res.render, pero no se porque:

```
Usuario.create({ nombre: req.body.nombre, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password }, 
        function (err, nuevoUsuario){ 
        if (err) {
            res.render('usuarios/create', {errors: err.errors, usuario: new Usuario({nombre: req.body.nombre, email: req.body.email})}) ;

        }else{
            nuevoUsuario.enviar_email_bienvenida();
            res.redirect('/usuarios');
        }
      });
},`
```

Comment: Revisa el objeto `errors` (`err.errors`) al parecer está llegando sin valor o bien no tiene el atributo `nombre` (tal vez sea `name` lo correcto).

Comment: El objeto errors donde debe estar? es el que esta en controllers del usuario, o en el modelo, o en la vista? saludos..

Comment: Lo recibes aquí `function (err, nuevoUsuario){` y lo utilizas aquí: `{errors: err.errors,`